# Remove all commits form bitbucket repositry

Tags: cmd, bitbucket, git-commit, git

I am new in git. I have a repositry in bitbucket. I want to remove all commits of repositry but it's shouldn't affect local files.

Which commands should I use.

How to do this.

Thanx

Comment: Do you want to remove the commits but leave the repo there, or would it be enough to delete the repo?

Comment: I just want to remove all commits because I need free space in my repositry for upcoming commits.

Comment: Please explain why you need to do that.

Comment: I have a repositry in bitbucket account. I am not a premium user so there are only 2 gb space for a repositry. And my repositry is full now. So I need space to new commits that's why I am trying to delete old commits from only remote.